# onClick event is not working on safari iOS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobile-safari, progressive-web-apps

I am developing a web app using React js. Every corner of the app works just fine when running on chrome for both desktop and android devices. The problem is that safari does not trigger `onClick={}` and I don't know why. Here are some considerations:

1. when the page load for the first time, trying to click on the element so early (less than 1 sec) would fire onClick. and after that, it won't work.
2. I've searched and tried styling the element: `cursor: 'pointer'`.
3. I've tried using [React-Tappable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tappable).
4. I've tried removing all `:hover` stylings as well.

Unfortunately, none of the aforementioned worked. Here is the chunk of code that I've written:

```html
<div
  onClick={this._open_profile_image}
  style={{
    position: "absolute",
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    width: "100%"
  }}
>
  <img
    onClick={this._open_profile_image}
    src={this.state.file}
    alt="Avatar"
    style={{
      width: "35vw",
      height: "35vw",
      marginTop: "15VH",
      borderRadius: "50%",
      boxShadow:
        "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05) 5px 5px 20px 7px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13) -5px -5px 30px 1px",
      border: "5px solid rgb(45, 148, 255)"
    }}
  />
  <div>
    {this.state.isOpen && (
      <Lightbox
        reactModalStyle={customStyles}
        mainSrc={this.state.file}
        onCloseRequest={() => this.setState({ isOpen: false })}
      />
    )}
  </div>
</div>;
```

I've used onClick on every `div` and its children but none of those fire. Any idea on how to fix this safari's bug?

Comment: Hi Amir, did you find any solution?

Comment: @AbdullahGürsu Yes! It's been so long. There is no legit fix for this. I just found a silly workaround which was to change the z-index of the 'div' and bring it closer so that it's touchable, e.g., z-index  = 1000 does the job but I don't know why safari does not fix these silly bugs. I think it's because they hate PWAs so much!